# Why does G-d, blessed be He, say that something did not enter His mind when He is all-knowing?

Tags: commentaries, theology

[Jeremiah 19:5](https://biblehub.com/jeremiah/19-5.htm) states:

> They have built high places to Baal on which to burn their children in the fire as offerings to Baal— something I never commanded or mentioned, **nor did it even enter My mind.**

Why does G-d, blessed be He, say that something did not enter His mind when we know that He is all-knowing (e.g. [Psalm 147:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Psalm%20147%3A5)).

My understanding is that it did not enter His mind as a *valid action*. I.e. this is not something that He would ever consider a valid course of action. But this is just my personal subjective interpretation that I came up with. The reason I'm asking this is because I need something more authoritative.

I tried looking at some commentaries on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.19.5?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en), but given that I can't really read any advanced Hebrew, I couldn't understand them and when I tried to translate them using online tools, they (e.g. Radak's commentary) come out as something incoherent.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it. It's a figure of speech that means "out of the question".

Comment: @shmosel Oh I didn't know. Maybe I *am* overthinking it, idk. If you have any authoritative source for that, just post it as an answer and I'll choose it I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that it did not enter His mind as a valid action. I.e. this is not something that He would ever consider a valid course of action.

That's basically correct. Metzudas Dovid translates it as "never entered My mind to ask such a thing." Radak references a few similar verses ([7:31](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.7.31?lang=bi), [32:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.32.35?lang=bi)) where the same language is used and translated by Targum as "was undesirable to me."

He also brings an interpretation (apparently from [Tanchuma](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Bechukotai.5.1?lang=bi)) that עלתה is an allusion to the human sacrifice (עולה) brought by [King Mesha](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.3.27?lang=bi) of Moab in a misguided attempt to appease Hashem. [Taanit 4a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.4a.10?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi) expounds the verse similarly but ties that clause to Avraham's sacrifice of Yitzchak, making the point that it was only commanded as a test and it never entered Hashem's mind that the sacrifice should occur.

Comment: More simply -- "I never intended."